# Generate Openssl signature

Tags: c#, openssl, cryptography, sha1

I'm trying to generate a signature file using my private key for a source file. the command works fine when I run it in command prompt. But when I try to do the same through the code, signature is not generating.

This is the code I'm using

```
    static void CreateOpenSSLSignature(string sourceFile, string sslPrivateKeyPath)
    {
        // Get required values
        if (File.Exists(signatureFilepath))
        {
            File.Delete(signatureFilepath);
        }
        var sigFile = File.Create(signatureFilepath);
        sigFile.Close();
        try
        {
            // Start decryption process
            Process myProcess = new Process();
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = openSSLPath + "\\bin\\openssl.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = openSSLPath + "/bin/";
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
            string arg = dgst -sha1 -sign sslPrivateKeyPath -binary sourcefilepath | openssl enc -base64             
            >> signaturefilepath
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arg.ToString();
            myProcess.Start();
            myProcess.WaitForExit(10000);            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are catching the exception and not doing anything with it, either throw it or log it to console.

Comment: I'm logging it, I've not mentioned it here. The problem I'm facing is once I form the command through the mentioned code and run it in command prompt it works, but the same command in this code isn't. And the code isn't throwing any error aswell.

Answer (score 0):

check this way. "set your openssl path":

```
string openSSlPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin";
try
{
    Process obj = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = openSSlPath + "\\openssl.exe",
                    WorkingDirectory = (openSSlPath ?? "")
                }
    };
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = obj.StartInfo;
    DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler defaultInterpolatedStringHandler = new DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler(115, 2);
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendLiteral("dgst -sha1 -sign ");
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendFormatted($"{sslPrivateKeyPath}");
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendLiteral(" -binary ");
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendFormatted($"{sourcefilepath}");
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendLiteral(" | openssl enc -base64 >> ");
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendFormatted($"{signaturefilepath}");
    startInfo.Arguments = defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.ToStringAndClear();
    obj.Start();
    obj.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can we use DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler in dotnet core?

Comment: Yes, I did it within a console application with .NET 6. what version do you mean?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.defaultinterpolatedstringhandler?view=net-7.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue#applies-to

Comment: I think dotnet core 3.1 framework doesn't support DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler.

Comment: Yes, it's just available in .NET 6 and greater.

Comment: Anything available for older framework?

Comment: First of all, try my suggested method on your machine with .NET 6 or higher. if it's worked for you you can use the generated string in your application on .net core 3.1.